# ImportError: cannot import name 'mobilenet_v2' from 'torchvision.models'

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

I want to run a fastai deep learning model on my pc. Not train, just run the pre-trained model on my PC. I have the .pth file. I tried to import the fastai module that I installed and I recieved the error :

`ImportError: cannot import name 'mobilenet_v2' from 'torchvision.models' (C:\file_path\__init__.py)`

The Code I tried to execute:

```
#From the fastai library
from fastai import *
from torchvision.models import * 
from fastai.vision import *
```

I can't find any solutions as to why I am getting this error.

Im running this code in anaconda, to be specific, the spyder IDE connected to my anaconda environment. I will re-edit this if anyone needs more specifications. Thank you.

Comment: This might seem like goofy question, but have you installed torchvision? `conda install  torchvision -c pytorch`

Comment: @Cecilia yes I have, along with other dependencies as stated on the fastai website.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I made a new conda environment, installed fastai with conda install -c pytorch -c fastai fastai and was able to execute your code above without errors.

Comment: I had the exact same issue  and I solved it as @Cecilia describe. It worked for me.

Comment: Alright. I will try doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished fixing this problem with my system. Uninstall any pytorch, torchvision by conda and pip. Uninstall fastai as well.

Go to https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and run the conda command there base on your cuda version and etc. Then

```
conda install -c fastai fastai
```

Comment: You also used Windows ? or it's a general not OS specific problem.

Comment: Yes I use Windows. The problem is fastai can't find the module in torchvision either because of a botched installation or the one installed just doesn't have that module. You can open \file_path\__init__.py from the error to see if that module really is there.

Comment: Just found this answer after running into the same issue. I initially installed `torchvision` without specifying a particular channel `-c`. This installed version `0.2.1`. However, when installing from channel `pytorch` using `conda install torchvision -c pytorch`, I got `0.7.0`, which is the latest. My assumption is that mobilenet_v2 was added somewhere between those two versions.